# Translate SQL to Rails Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Can anyone help me to translate SQL to Rails Active Record Query?

```
Station Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "stations".* FROM "stations" WHERE "stations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "f8cc6584-9794-4863-9e3a-7ac05a1b5d46"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Connector Load (4.0ms)  SELECT "connectors".* FROM "connectors" WHERE "connectors"."station_id" = $1 AND "connectors"."id" IN ($2, $3)  [["station_id", "f8cc6584-9794-4863-9e3a-7ac05a1b5d46"], ["id", "a476c0a6-bccb-42c7-935f-541031344860"], ["id", "e8e8e80b-6f73-4a66-9345-ae59a042b56d"]]
```

Station has many Connectors. Have tried various ways, but none of them is exact like SQL above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If a connector belongs to a station (if that relationship is set in the connector model) then you can try joining and filtering with `where`;

```
Connector
  .joins(:station)
  .where(
    station_id: "f8cc6584-9794-4863-9e3a-7ac05a1b5d46",
    id: ["a476c0a6-bccb-42c7-935f-541031344860", "e8e8e80b-6f73-4a66-9345-ae59a042b56d"]
  )
```

Similarly you can find the station, then get its connectors, but this involes two queries (and it'll fail if ther's no station wich such id in the database);

```
Station
  .find("f8cc6584-9794-4863-9e3a-7ac05a1b5d46")
  .connectors
  .where(id: ["a476c0a6-bccb-42c7-935f-541031344860", "e8e8e80b-6f73-4a66-9345-ae59a042b56d"])
```